# Sending goal for navigation using SimpleActionClient

Tags: ros, navigation, simpleactionclient, callbacks, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I was able to send goal to the robot, but I wanted to know when the robot has reached the goal by using callback. Does anyone has any idea how this can be done in the sendGoal function of the SimpleActionClient?

Thanks,
TayXR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10150/sending-goal-for-navigation-using-simpleactionclient/) by [TayXR](https://answers.ros.org/users/598/tayxr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-02**:
It can't be done in sendGoal as the idea of actionlib is to have the (long-term) action run in the background. It can be done using SimpleActionClient, however.
This tutorial describes the process:
[Sending Goals](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can be done using Actionlib under C++. Check this link: http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Callback%20Based%20Simple%20Action%20Client

For an example check the face_recognition package, it uses exactly the same structure as the one in the link I sent you. However I'm still looking for a python equivalent of that as there is no tutorials about it.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1